# Google Fusion Table Heatmap

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to create a Google Fusion table heatmap. I've copy and pasted the code from [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-heatmap) and it works fine on localhost. I then change my API key and column name to **loc** and use my fusion table id `AIzaSyAoiA3rVUoIRrsxje8JTWr599YqnHpHvCA` but it just isn't rendering.

What am I missing? I'm guessing it's a setting my fusion table itself but I can't see any other configurable options. I've shared the table publically.

```
  var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
  select: 'loc',
  from: '1vtep10enWGFG1NBblFkycgjOiD6O-QKif3N3Ku9G'
},
heatmap: {
  enabled: true
}
});

layer.setMap(map);
}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAoiA3rVUoIRrsxje8JTWr599YqnHpHvCA&callback=initMap">
```

My complete HTML code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Fusion Tables heatmaps</title>
<style>
  html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  #map {
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
<script>
  function initMap() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
center: {lat: 50.813215, lng: -0.407896},
zoom: 8
});

var layer = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer({
query: {
  select: 'loc',
  from: '1vtep10enWGFG1NBblFkycgjOiD6O-QKif3N3Ku9G'
},
heatmap: {
  enabled: true
}
});

layer.setMap(map);
}
</script>
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyAoiA3rVUoIRrsxje8JTWr599YqnHpHvCA&callback=initMap">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share error/s that appear in the console if there are any.

Comment: It looks to me that if you go to your FusionTable, click on "publish" and then on HTML/Javascript the recommended code doesn't use the FusionTables "heatmap", it uses a FusionTables API query to populate a [Google Maps Javascript API v3 heatmap](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer).